# Banishment in an Area that Prevents Teleportation

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, forgotten-realms

Pathfinder rules in the Forgotten Realms setting. The campaign is currently set in Myth Drannor. A high-level Wizard battled some of the resident fiends and used banishment. He successfully penetrated SR and overcame their saving throws.

Myth Drannor has powerful abjurations in place that prevent the fiends from teleporting out of the city, and prevents them summoning other fiends into the city. In fact it prevents all teleportation into, and out of, the city. Since the banishment is not a conjuration spell, but an abjuration, I went with having it work and sent the fiends back to the lower planes.

Was this the correct interpretation of the rules, and intent of the Myth Drannor setting, or was this botched on my part?

Comment: Nice first question! I've removed the [tag:dungeons-and-dragons] tag, since it is for questions that apply across multiple editions of D&D..

Comment: Thank you. Consistency is ideal, but I worry the encounters were trivialized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Yes, your interpretation is correct.

For sake of explanation, we will use Silverymoon:

> The Wards of Silverymoon
>
> ***The city of Silverymoon is protected by a powerful magical effect called a mythal***. This potent form of elven high magic forbids the casting of several types of spells, causes other spells to be permanently in effect, and allows the denizens of Silverymoon to use still other spells with a word. The mythal’s effects cover the city itself, plus an area 1,000 yards beyond its limits in all directions (even up into the sky and down into the earth).
>
> ***Spells with the death, evil, or teleportation descriptor, conjuration (summoning) spells, and evocation [fire] spells*** are all forbidden by the mythal of Silverymoon. Any attempt to cast such a spell ***fails automatically***, though the spell slot is used up normally.

There is an elven prestige class that specifically deal with these mythals, called the [Spellguard of New Silverymoon](https://seekers-of-the-misty-isle.obsidianportal.com/wikis/spellguard-of-silverymoon).

Source: [Player's Guide to Faerun](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786931345)

[Myth Drannor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myth_Drannor) is/was an elven city, that utilized the same types of security mythals. According to Wikipedia:

> Myth Drannor, formerly known as Cormanthor the City of Song, was once considered to be the most beautiful and peaceful of any of the cities in Faerûn. At its peak, no city could compare to the glory of Myth Drannor. All races lived in complete harmony for the first time in memory, without fear or corruption. However, the city has been in ruins for many years. The city was once protected by a device called a mythal which is one of the greatest spells in perhaps all of the Realms. The mythal is a protective spell which shields Myth Drannor from outside forces and from general harm.